# Mass renormalization with counterterm for scalar field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, scattering, feynman-diagrams

Sidney coleman in his lecture 253a of QFT stated that " one-meson-to-one-meson S-matrix element, we should find it equal to 1" i.e $$\langle p'|S|p\rangle = (2\pi)^32E_p\delta^{(3)}(\vec{p}'-\vec{p})\tag{1}$$ for the scalar theory $$ \mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2} \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial^{\mu} \phi-\frac{\mu^{2}}{2} \phi^{2}-g\phi\psi^*\psi+\partial_{\mu} \psi \partial^{\mu} \psi^*-m^2\psi^*\psi$$
But a single meson state of this theory can decay into nucleon and anti nucleon state. Then how come we can use the condition (1) to fix the counterterm as given in coleman's note?(https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5013). I know similar question was raised in [Renormalization and Particle Decay](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/375991/renormalization-and-particle-decay) but the answer was never accepted and inconclusive.

Comment: doesn’t (1) just normalise the free particle states?  it’s not the full S-matrix element, it’s the interaction-free piece, right?

Comment: but if you have a single meson state, all other s-matrix elements will be zero any way

Comment: i don’t understand what you mean. the full set of S-matrix elements encode all possible interactions, with any number of initial and final states. this two-point amplitude is just one entry. right?

Comment: My precise question is why the condition 1 is true. Because there are other prbablity amplitude for example meson$\rightarrow$nucleon-anti-nucleon which are non zero

Comment: (1) is true by assumption, it is a normalisation convention that follows from requiring that since there is initially one particle in the whole universe (and in the absence of interaction) it makes sense to normalise things such that the entire energy in the universe is that of that single particle.

Comment: you can read about the details of the relevant derivation in Landau and Lifshits QED volume of their course in theoretical physics.

Comment: remember it is in the absence of interactions that it holds. more generally, there are interaction terms that appear additively on the RHS of 1, but fixing the leading term normalisation as in 1 fixes the normalisation of all subsequent terms from interactions.

Comment: For non-interacting theory I agree it is true, but when the interaction is switched on then also he has considered this result. Please see the refered pdf

Comment: He precisely want this condition to hold even when interaction is turned on and

Comment: i don’t understand what you mean. it is standard to expand the S matrix as S=1+iT, and (1) specifies what 1 in 1+iT means in the case of two-point amplitudes. you can of course use that result when you go on to calculate iT if you wish.

Comment: eqn (1) is just computing or specifying what 1 means in 1+iT, not the full S.

Comment: oki i understand your point but what about iT or the other terms in the perturbative expansion? because if you consider atleast order g, you are going to get meson decay

Comment: yes, indeed, you get decay and T gets a corresponding imaginary part as dictated by the optical theorem (unitarity).  i really recommend you study the Landau and Lifshits lectures QED volume, they go through all this in detail and particularly clearly. there’s always weinberg of course, etc., but LL discusses insights that are absent in the more standard texts.

Comment: ok thanks for the reference. I have not studied the optical theorem yet, one last question, is this T the reason behind the phase term that appears for full hamiltonian

Comment: i don’t know about any phase in H

Comment: not for H but for asymtotic out state